# Android: How to left align a text with the title text toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I would like to align my red text (not included in the Toolbar!) with the title in the Toolbar (left align). Is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: Posting some code will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Material Design guidelines the Toolbar text has a margin left of 72 dp.

Take a look at the section Keylines and spacing [Here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing)

Add the same spacing to your textview and they should be aligned